# Getting the latest addition in a m2m_changed signal in Django

Tags: python, django, model, signals, m2m

I'm trying to use the m2m_changed signal in Django to create a notification for when a post is 'liked'. Right now, I have a post_save signal functioning to create a notification for a comment. In my m2m_changed signal function, printing the queryset for likes on a post pre_add and post_add shows the addition of the user who liked the post when the signal is sent, ie 
pre = QuerySet [User: TestUser] and 
post = QuerySet [User: TestUser, User: test_user].

What method can I call on instance.likes to return the user associated with this m2m_changed signal? Or can I call a diff method on the pre and post query sets to return this one user? I'm looking to create the notification by

Notification.objects.create(post=instance, user=?????, liked=True, date_posted=?????)

And also, is there a way I can set date_posted for the notification to equal the datetime of when the signal is sent?

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('photo_blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    liked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Comment)
def auto_create_comment_notification(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Notification.objects.create(post=instance.post, comment=instance, date_posted=instance.date_posted)


@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Post.likes.through)
def auto_create_like_notification(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
if action == "pre_add":
    print(instance.likes.all())
if action == "post_add":
    print(instance.likes.latest())
```

My Post model looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=2200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('photo_blog-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def get_api_like_url(self):
        return reverse('photo_blog-post_like_api', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.photo.path)

        output_size = (450, (img.height / img.width) * 450)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.photo.path)
```

Comment: Have you tried `instance.likes.through.objects.last().user`?

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for. Is there something similar for action == 'post_remove' to find the user that was removed?